# Windows 10 LTSC randomly Shuts down after approx 1 Hour of use

Tags: windows, bug

I have a modern Laptop that shipped with windows 10
i recently upgraded to 11
i thought of installing windows 7 for better gaming experience but LTSC struck my mind and i decided to give it a try
when it installed everything worked fine except for when i installed all the drivers, rebooted and and started using it. It shut down after an hour of internet browsing
i thought it must have been an important update but that has happned 4 times as of writing this question here
This has never happned because previous windows 10 and current windows 11 work fine and do not go bye bye
its not activated even tho it should be cuz i am on free 90 day trial anyone knows sumthing bout this?
Help!

Comment: Update BIOS (UEFI), Power drivers, and all other drivers and test

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'e been trying vfor about a months now.  ODdly home does not cause this